# The existence of analytical branch of the logarithm of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

$\Omega$ is a convex open set in $\mathbb {C}^n$ and $f$ is an analytical function **Edit:** *without zero point on $\Omega$*, then can we define an analytical branch of $\ln {f}$ on $\Omega$ ?

Comment: sorry, I have corrected it.

Comment: No problem. However, I made your change in the question clearly visible, in order for my answer to still make sense.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am happy to report that, yes, you can define $\log f$ even in much greater generality than in your situation.
Namely, if you have a *real* differentiable manifold $M$ and a function $f\in \mathcal C^\infty (M)$ never zero on $M$, then $f$ has a $\mathcal C^\infty $ logarithm 
as soon as the first De Rham cohomology group of $M$ vanishes: $H^1_{DR}(M, \mathbb R)=0$.

The definition of the logarithm is straightforward: fix a point $x_0\in M$ and define  $$(\log f)(x)= \int_\gamma \frac {df}{f}    $$
where $\gamma$ is a differentiable path joining $x_0$ to $x$, along which we can integrate the *closed*  $1$-form $\frac {dg}{g}$.
The vanishing cohomology hypothesis ensures that the value of $\log f$ at $x$ does not depend of the path $\gamma$ chosen.

If $M$ happens to be a complex holomorphic manifold and if $f\in \mathcal O(M)$ is holomorphic, then the logarithm of $f$ will automatically be holomorphic: $\log f\in \mathcal O(M)$.
This applies to your case since a simply connected manifold -and *a fortiori* a convex set in a vector space- has zero first De Rham cohomology group.

Finally, just for old times' sake, let me sum this up in the language of classical physics :
$$\text{Every conservative vector field has a potential}$$

**A variant**
 Specialists in complex manifolds are addicted to the exact sequence of sheaves on the complex manifold $X$:
$$0\to 2i\pi \mathbb Z\to \mathcal O_X \stackrel {exp}{\to} \mathcal O^\ast_X  \to 0  $$

A portion of the associated cohomology long exact sequence  is 
$$ \Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X) \stackrel {exp}{\to} \Gamma(X,\mathcal O^\ast_X) \to H^1(X,\mathbb Z)  $$
which shows again that every nowhere vanishing holomorphic function on $X$ is an exponential (in other words: has a logarithm) as soon as $H^1(X,\mathbb Z)=0$.

Comment: What is $g$? Where does it come from?

Comment: @scineram: I wrote  $g$ instead of the correct $f$. Thanks a lot for noticing this typo, now corrected.

Comment: Why require the region convex?

Comment: Dear @Ren: because Hezuado asked about a convex open set in his question!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, are you available to answer some questions about your answer? I am in doubt if I should consider $df = \partial f + \bar{\partial} f$ and how could I use this to show that $exp(log(f)) = f$.

Answer (score 12):

**Edit:** I misread the question and only address the case $n=1$.

---

If you allow the function $f$ to have roots, then the answer is clearly **no**. There is no analytic branch of the logarithm of $z$ in *any* neighborhood of $0$.

If you exclude roots, the answer is **yes**.

---

More generally:

> Let $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic with $0 \notin f(G)$ and assume that $G$ is a simply connected domain (in particular $G$ convex suffices). Then $f$ has a holomorphic logarithm $g: G \to \mathbb{C}$, that is $f(z) = e^{g(z)}$ for all $z \in G$.

Fix $z_0 \in G$ arbitrarily, choose $g(z_0)$ in such a way that $f(z_0) = \exp{g(z_0)}$ and put $g(z) = g(z_0) + \int_{z_0}^{z} \frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}\,dw$. Check that $g$ is well-defined, holomorphic, and that $\frac{d}{dz} [f \cdot e^{-g}] = 0$, hence $f = e^g$.

Comment: Your answer is definitely right when applied to one variable, but how can we generalize it to the situation of multiple one?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I only addressed the one-dimensional case. I missed that you were talking about $\mathbb{C}^n$. I don't know off the top of my head. I need to think a little.

Comment: I don't have the expertise to say anything at the moment, I'm not feeling comfortable enough with several complex variables and it's getting late. I'll leave the answer here for the moment, hoping that it's useful in some way.

Comment: Yess, well definedness of the integral above has to see with the fact that in a simply-connected domain, the integral is independent of path.

Comment: @gary: Are you asking? Anyway: yes, of course.

Comment: @t.b, no;I mistakenly thought the OP had asked why the integral is well-defined.

Comment: Here is how I came about this question: consider the set of all the symmetric complex $n \times n$ matrix and its subset $H$ consisting of all symmetric nonsingular complex $n \times n$ matrix $B$ such that Re$B > 0$ (positive definite), then function $f:B \to {(\det (B))^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ is well-defined and analytic on $H$.