# an equivalent condition of entire function without zero

Tags: entire-functions

### Show that an entire function $f$ has no zeros if and only if there exists another entire function $g$ so that $f=e^g$.

For if part, easy because exp function has no zero and is of course entire.
For only if part, I thought that f can be expanded as Taylor series centred at 0, and let g(z) = z*(f^(n)(0))^(1/n), so f = exp(g).
Is that correct method?
I think that g is multivalued. Is that a problem?

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74920/the-existence-of-analytical-branch-of-the-logarithm-of-a-holomorphic-function

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* If $f=\exp(g)$, then $f'=g'f$. So define $\displaystyle g(z) = w_0+\int_0^z \frac{f'(w)}{f(w)} dw$, where $w_0$ is such that $f(0)=\exp(w_0)$, which exists since $f(0)\ne0$ and the image of $\exp$ is 
$\mathbb C \setminus \{ {0}\}$.